# Button sit at bottom of page centered

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like a scroll to the top button to sit at the bottom, much like a footer.  Current Behavior: I have an array I'm filtering through and displaying different lengths of data.  When there is only one item in a certain category the button will move all the way to the top of the page under the item.  Wanted Behavior: I would like the button to stay at the bottom and not move, but not sticky.  my button styling is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react"

// components
import SelectStatus from "../components/SelectStatus"
import RepoCard from "../components/RepoCard"

// Context
import { GithubContext } from "../context/GithubContext"

// Material UI Stuff
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField"
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card"
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container"

// context

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
  },
  card: {
    display: "flex",
    marginBottom: 10,
    minHeight: 90,
  },
  form: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
  content: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },

  jobField: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
  grid: {
    padding: 0,
  },

  dashboardContainer: {
    marginTop: 70,
    padding: 10,
  },
  loading: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
}))

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  language: "All",
  search: "",
}

const Profile = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE)
  const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false)
  const [created, setCreated] = useState(false)
  const { data } = useContext(GithubContext)

  const handleUpdated = () => {
    setUpdated(!updated)
    data &&
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (updated) return a.updated_at > b.updated_at ? -1 : 1
        return a.updated_at > b.updated_at ? 1 : -1
      })
  }

  const handleCreated = () => {
    setCreated(!created)
    data &&
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (created) return a.created_at > b.created_at ? -1 : 1
        return a.created_at > b.created_at ? 1 : -1
      })
  }

  const handleInputChange = (field) => (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [field]: e.target.value })
  }

  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 85, marginBottom: 85 }}>
        <Container className={classes.dashboardContainer}>
          <Card className={classes.card} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <CardContent className={classes.content}>
              <div className={classes.form}>
                <Grid
                  container
                  spacing={2}
                  alignItems='center'
                  justify='space-between'
                >
                  <Grid item sm={4} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
                    <SelectStatus
                      language={formData.language}
                      handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item sm={4} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
                    <TextField
                      className={classes.jobField}
                      margin='normal'
                      fullWidth
                      id='search'
                      name='search'
                      label='Search by Title'
                      placeholder='Search by Title'
                      onChange={handleInputChange("search")}
                      value={formData.search}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item sm={2} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
                    <Button
                      fullWidth
                      variant='contained'
                      color='primary'
                      onClick={handleUpdated}
                    >
                      Updated {updated ? "(oldest)" : "(newest)"}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item sm={2} xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
                    <Button
                      fullWidth
                      variant='contained'
                      color='primary'
                      onClick={handleCreated}
                    >
                      Created {created ? "(oldest)" : "(newest)"}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Container>
        {!data ? (
          <h1 className={classes.loading}>Initializing Repos...</h1>
        ) : (
          <Container style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            {!data ? (
              <div style={{ placeItems: "center" }}>Loading...</div>
            ) : (
              <Grid container alignItems='center' spacing={4}>
                {data &&
                  data
                    .filter((data) => {
                      if (formData.language === "All") return true
                      return data.language === formData.language
                    })
                    .filter((data) => {
                      if (formData.search === "") return true
                      return (data.name + data.language)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .includes(formData.search.toLowerCase())
                    })
                    .map((user) => <RepoCard key={user.id} user={user} />)}
              </Grid>
            )}
          </Container>
        )}
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          color='primary'
          disableElevation
          style={{
            borderRadius: 0,
            display: "block",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            position: "relative",
            marginTop: "80px"

          }}
        >
          Back to Top
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Profile
```

Comment: we'll have to see a bit more of your page in order to identify the problem. While I am not great at React I don't see anything wrong with the button itself

Comment: @Joeri I have added the rest of the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` and `space-around` feature. like below:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
         your items
    </div>
    <Button
        variant='contained'
        color='primary'
        disableElevation
        style={{
            borderRadius: 0,
            elevation: "disabled",
            display: "block",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            marginTop: "80px",
        }}
    >
        Back to Top
    </Button>
</div>
```

Style:

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Using this you split your content to two part.

First part which will be your array items will be shown at the top.

The second part which is your `button` will be shown at the bottom.

This is because your making a space between first part and second part by using `space-around` of `justify-content`.

Comment: tried this method and it seems the button is still moving up and down with the content

Answer (score 0):

without sticky or fixed the only thing i can think of is using position: absolute; and bottom: 0; or placing them in a container with some combination of the same, then positioning it as needed. same as Joeri in the comments, would need a bit more context to help :) good luck!